# How to find the intecept x and y coordinates from 4 data points in Excel?

Tags: math, excel-formula

I have two points which form one line: (1,4) and (3,6), and another two which form another line: (2,1) and (4,2). These lines are continuous and I can find their intersection points by finding the equation for each line, and then equating them to find the x value at the intersection point, and then the y value.

i.e. for the first line, the equation is y = x + 3, and the second is y = 0.5x. At the intersection the y values are the same so x + 3 = 0.5x. So x = -6. Subbing this back into either of the equations gives a y value of -3.

From those steps, I now know that the intersection point is (-6,-3). The problem is I need to do the same steps in Excel, preferably as one formula. Can anyone give me some advice on how I would start this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its long but here it is:
Define x1,y1 and x2,y2 for the 1st line and x3,y3 and x4,y4 for the second.

```
x = (x2y1-x1y2)(x4-x3)-(x4y3-x3y4)(x2-x1) / [ (x2-x1)(y4-y3) - (x4-x3)(y2-y1) ]
y = (x2y1-x1y2)(y4-y3)-(x4y3-x3y4)(y2-y1) / [ (x2-x1)(y4-y3) - (x4-x3)(y2-y1) ]
```

Note that the denominators are the same. They will be ZERO! when the system has no solution. So you may want to check that in another cell and conditionally compute the answer.

Essentially, this formula is derived by solving a system of equations for x and y by hand using generic points (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3), and (x4,y4). Easier yet, is solving the system by hand using well developed linear algebra concepts.

Wikipedia outlines this procedure well: [Line-line intersection.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection)

Also, this website describes all the different formulas and lets you put in whatever data you have in any mixed format and provides many details of the solutions: [Everything about 2 lines.](http://www.ambrsoft.com/MathCalc/Line/TwoLinesIntersection/TwoLinesIntersection.htm)

Comment: Thanks for that. It appears the x value is correct but the y value results in the same number. Would you happen to know why this is?

Comment: @david_10001 I just double checked the formula. It is correct. Are you sure you changed the Xs to Yx in the numerators for those terms?

Comment: Ah yep, picked up my mistake. Thank you!

Comment: It's good to be given the simple formula, but it would be helpful for the future to mention linear algebra and solving matrix equations.  This formula works for 2 linear equations with two unknowns, but linear algebra and matricies work for any number of equations and unknowns.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added more information to the post. @duffymo

Answer (score 1):

Here's a matrix based solution:

```
x - y = -3
0.5*x - y = 0
```

Written as a matrix equation (I apologize for the poor typesetting):

```
| 1.0  -1.0 |{ x }   { -3 }
| 0.5  -1.0 |{ y } = {  0 }
```

You can invert this matrix or use LU decomposition to solve it to get the answer.  That method will work for any number of cases where you have one equation for each unknown.

This is easy to do by hand:

1. Subtract the second equation from the first: 0.5*x = -3
2. Divide both sides by 0.5: x = -6
3. Substitute this result into the other equation: y = 0.5*x = -3